# Programmatically creating multiple instances of asp web app with different domain names and in different Virtual Machines

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I created a new ASP.NET MVC web app which is responsible for school management. Now I want to create new web app that helps to deploy this app with new sub-domain and new database for new registred client.
What is the best approach to do this work ? 
I have small information about this type of apps, according to this information I think it is some thing related to services provided by web hosting companies such as Microsoft Azure which provides creation and configuration of Virtual Machines programmatically with the ability to deploy app to this new created VMs also programmatically ! am I write ?! 
If you still didn't understand my problem kindly try to visit shopify (https://www.shopify.com/) which provides store creation for non professionals with the same way that I want in my project.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below creates a new virtual directory on the IIS host.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new virtual directory on the iis host.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iisHostPath">The iis host path.</param>
    /// <param name="physicalPath">The physical path to the directory.</param>
    /// <param name="virtualDirectoryName">The virtual directory name.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultDocument">The defualt document to set.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the virtual directory was created else false.</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// iisHostPath : [servername]/[service]/[websiteID]/[Root] : localhost/W3SVC/1/Root
    /// defaultDocument : [document] : default.aspx
    /// </example>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>iisHostPath : [servername]/[service]/[websiteID]/[Root] : localhost/W3SVC/1/Root</para>
    /// <para>defaultDocument : [document] : default.aspx</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual bool CreateVirtualDirectory(string iisHostPath, string physicalPath,
        string virtualDirectoryName, string defaultDocument)
    {
        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(iisHostPath))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("IIS path can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid IIS path should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(physicalPath))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Physical can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid physical path should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(virtualDirectoryName))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Virtual directory name can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid virtual directory name should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultDocument))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Default document can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid default document should be specified."));

        // Create a new directory entry
        // instance to the iis machine.
        DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry(
            "IIS://" + iisHostPath);

        // Add the iis virtual directory
        // to the iis collection.
        DirectoryEntry virtName = localMachine.Children.Add(virtualDirectoryName, "IIsWebVirtualDir");

        // Commit the changes for the account.
        virtName.CommitChanges();

        // Assign default properties.
        virtName.Properties["Path"][0] = physicalPath;
        virtName.Properties["DefaultDoc"][0] = defaultDocument;
        virtName.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;

        // These properties are necessary for an application to be created.
        virtName.Properties["AppFriendlyName"][0] = virtualDirectoryName;
        virtName.Properties["AppIsolated"][0] = "1";
        virtName.Properties["AppRoot"][0] = "/LM/" + iisHostPath;

        // Commit the changes for the account.
        virtName.CommitChanges();

        // Close the connections.
        virtName.Close();
        localMachine.Close();

        // Return success.
        return true;
    }
```

The code below creates a new web site on the II host.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new web site on the iis host.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iisHostPath">The iis host path.</param>
    /// <param name="websiteID">The unique web site id.</param>
    /// <param name="websiteName">The name of the web site.</param>
    /// <param name="physicalPath">The physical path to the root directory.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the web site was created else false.</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// iisHostPath : [servername]/[service] : localhost/W3SVC
    /// websiteID : [number] : 454354
    /// </example>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>iisHostPath : [servername]/[service] : localhost/W3SVC</para>
    /// <para>websiteID : [number] : 454354</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual bool CreateWebSite(string iisHostPath,
        string websiteID, string websiteName, string physicalPath)
    {
        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(iisHostPath))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("IIS path can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid IIS path should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(websiteID))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Web site id can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid web site id should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(websiteName))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Web site name can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid web site name should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(physicalPath))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Physical can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid physical path should be specified."));

        // Create a new directory entry
        // instance to the iis machine.
        DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry(
            "IIS://" + iisHostPath);

        // Add the iis web site
        // to the iis collection.
        DirectoryEntry siteName = localMachine.Children.Add(websiteID, "IIsWebServer");

        // Assign the web site properties.
        siteName.Properties["ServerComment"][0] = websiteName;
        siteName.CommitChanges();

        // Commit the changes for the account.
        siteName.CommitChanges();

        // Add the iis web site
        // to the iis collection.
        DirectoryEntry rootName = siteName.Children.Add("Root", "IIsWebVirtualDir");

        // Assign the web site properties.
        rootName.Properties["Path"][0] = physicalPath;
        rootName.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;

        // Commit the changes for the account.
        rootName.CommitChanges();

        // Close the connections.
        rootName.Close();
        siteName.Close();
        localMachine.Close();

        // Return success.
        return true;
    }
```

The code below sets the port number on a web site on the IIS host.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set a port number to a web site on the iis host.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iisHostPath">The iis host path.</param>
    /// <param name="portNumber">The port number.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the port number was assigned else false.</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// iisHostPath : [servername]/[service]/[websiteID] : localhost/W3SVC/1
    /// </example>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>iisHostPath : [servername]/[service]/[websiteID] : localhost/W3SVC/1</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual bool SetWebSitePortNumber(string iisHostPath, int portNumber)
    {
        // Validate the inputs.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(iisHostPath))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("IIS path can not be null.",
                new System.Exception("A valid IIS path should be specified."));

        // Validate the inputs.
        if (portNumber < 1)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Port number not valid.",
                new System.Exception("The port number must be greater than zero."));

        // Create a new directory entry
        // instance to the iis machine.
        DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry(
            "IIS://" + iisHostPath);

        // Set the web site port number.
        localMachine.Properties["ServerBindings"][0] = ":" + portNumber + ":";

        // Commit the changes for the account.
        localMachine.CommitChanges();

        // Close the connections.
        localMachine.Close();

        // Return success.
        return true;
    }
```

Note that `localMachine.Properties["ServerBindings"][0] =` refers to `Bindings` in the `Advanced Settings` of your web site in IIS.

[image: AdvancedSettings]